# Not able to play the playlist in MediaPlayer continously in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

```
private void initPlayer() throws MalformedURLException{

    File dir =  new File("../Railway PRS/Videos");
    if (!dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()){
        //System.out.println("Cannot find audio source directory: " + dir);
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("File Not Found");
        alert.setHeaderText("Video File Not Found: ");
        alert.setContentText("Place the video folder onto the following location: ../Railway/Videos/File.mp4");
        alert.showAndWait();            
    }

    final List<MediaPlayer> players = new ArrayList<>();
    File folder = new File("../Railway UTS/Videos");
    File[] listofFiles = folder.listFiles();
    File file;// = null;        
    for (i = 0; i < listofFiles.length; i++){
        file = new File(listofFiles[i].getName());
        //Media media = new Media(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
        players.add(new MediaPlayer(new Media(file.toURI().toURL().toString())));
    }
    if (players.isEmpty()) {
        //System.out.println("No audio found in " + dir);
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Audio File Not Found");
        alert.setHeaderText("Audio File?");
        alert.setContentText("Place the videos onto the following location: ../Railway/Videos/File.mp4");
        alert.showAndWait();  
    }


    mediaview = new MediaView(players.get(0));
    //mediaview1 = new MediaView(players.get(0));        
    for ( j = 0; j < players.size(); j++){            
        final MediaPlayer player = players.get(j);
        final MediaPlayer nextPlayer = players.get((j + 1) % players.size());  
        player.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mediaview.setMediaPlayer(nextPlayer);
                nextPlayer.play();
                //nextPlayer.setCycleCount(nextPlayer.INDEFINITE);
                //player.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);                        
            }
        });
    }
    mediaview.setMediaPlayer(players.get(0));        
    mediaview.getMediaPlayer().play();
    basepane.getChildren().addAll(mediaview); 


}
```

The above code plays the video(playlist) only once. I want it to play the video(playlist) continously. If I set the cyclecount to Indefinite it repeats the first video while playing the second video means we can hear the sound of first video. I want the playlist to play continuously non-stop unless the application is exited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just put the following line in the for loop and it will work.It will play the video/videos in cycle.

```
nameofmediaplayer.seek(DURATION.ZERO);
```